# Textcontrol doesn't make second page with cell borders

Tags: c#

I have code to make several pages with the same layout. There will only the first page is correct. The other pages shows no text anymore and the cell borders are not painted. Can't dispose the borders or cell's.

```
int tableID = 10;

textControl.Tables.Add(4, 8, tableID);

TXTextControl.Table table = textControl.Tables.GetItem(tableID);

table.Cells.GetItem(1, 1).Text = "Rooster";
table.Cells.GetItem(1, 2).Text = "Maandag";
table.Cells.GetItem(1, 3).Text = "Dinsdag";
table.Cells.GetItem(1, 4).Text = "Woensd";
table.Cells.GetItem(1, 5).Text = "Donderd";
table.Cells.GetItem(1, 6).Text = "Vrijdag";
table.Cells.GetItem(1, 7).Text = "Zaterdag";
table.Cells.GetItem(1, 8).Text = "Zondag";

table.Cells.GetItem(2, 1).Text = "Ochtend";
table.Cells.GetItem(3, 1).Text = "Middag";
table.Cells.GetItem(4, 1).Text = "Avond";

SetCellFormat(table);

textControl.Selection.Bold = true;
textControl.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = TXTextControl.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
textControl.Selection.Length = 0;
```

This is my first post here, hope I did it well. Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: is this winforms with custom controls or wpf or something else? might be useful to know..

Comment: This is winforms with in c# with txtextcontrol as custom control

Comment: It sounds like you either use the control wrong or the custom control itself has bugs. Without knowing the custom control we can't really help you

Comment: The txt5extcontrol is a package where you can download fom txtextcontol website (the light version) for free. If you want more it can be bought. They used to have a forum but that is deleted.

Comment: I have solved it. TableID must be another number then the previous number.